# How to get text after br tag using Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I try to get text after br

Example HTML

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text data-aura-rendered-by="xx" class="xx">
  <span>
     "Test1"
     <br>
     "Test2"
  </span>
</lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

My Robot Script

```
${getText}=   Get Text   xpath=//lightning-formatted-rich-text[@class='xx']//text()[preceding-sibling::br]
```

But after execute robot return error WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: It looks like your framework just manage element and attribute types. There is some access to wider features by the means of [`Evaluate XPath`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Evaluate%20Xpath) keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `Get Text` is expecting an element, but you a passing the actual text. I only see the solution to parse the text after being obtained.

See below my example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           String

*** Test Cases ***
Get Text After BR
    Open Browser    file://${CURDIR}/example_html.html    ${BROWSER}
    ${getText}=    Get Text    xpath=//lightning-formatted-rich-text[@class='xx']
    @{text}=    Split String    ${getText}
    Log Many    @{text}
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```